# Rails - Show which category a tutorial belongs to in the tutorial index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, belongs-to

I have a `tutorial` model and a `tutorial_category` model. I have linked the two together using a `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship. In my tutorials index view, I am looping through the tutorials like so: `<% @tutorials.each do |tutorial| %>`. Inside that loop, I am wanting to display the category each tutorial belongs to. I'm trying to do it like `<%= tutorial.tutorial_categories.title %>` (title is an attr in the tutorial_category model and I also have :tutorial_id as an attribute in the tutorial_category model. And :tutorial_category_id is an attr in the tutorial model, for that matter).

Here is the index action in my tutorials controller:

```
def index
   @tutorials = Tutorial.all
   @tutorial = Tutorial.new
   @tutorial_categories = TutorialCategory.select("DISTINCT title, id")

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @tutorials }
  end
end
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. From my experience, this should all work correctly, although it's been a few months since I've written any Ruby code so I'm probably missing something stupid here. Any help would be appreciated!

**Update: my models**

```
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :tutorial_category_id
  belongs_to :tutorial_category
end

class TutorialCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :tutorial_id
  has_many :tutorials
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to list the tutorial categories next to tutorials then do the following:

```
def index
   @tutorials = Tutorial.includes(:tutorial_category)
   @tutorial = Tutorial.new
   ...
  end
end
```

Then you can iterate over them

```
<% @tutorials.each do |tutorial| %>
  <%= tutorial.tutorial_category.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Tutorial categories has_many tutorials. I'm trying what you gave for that, but am still getting an undefined method for 'title'

Comment: In your question you wrote `tutorial.tutorial_categories.title`, make sure it's singular like in my answer and not plural. Also make sure you've run all your migrations. Perhaps you should add the models to your question as well.

Comment: Yeah I made it singular. Updated my question w/ the models

Comment: ID columns aren't usually added to `attr_accessible`. Go into your `rails console` and type `TutorialCategory`, see that the column title actually shows up. Then check if `TutorialCategory.first.title` returns any errors.